# Check if a vector lies in the span a subset of columns of a matrix in Sage

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sage

I'm new to programming with Sage. I have a rectangular R*C matrix (R rows and C columns) and the rank of M is (possibly) smaller than both R and C. I want to check if a target vector T is in the span of a subset of columns of M. I have written the following code in Sage (I haven't included the whole code because the way I get M and T are rather cumbersome). I just want to check if the code does what I want.

Briefly, this is what my code is trying to do: M is my given matrix, I first check that T is indeed in the span of columns of M (the first if condition). If they do, I proceed to trim down M (which had C columns) to a matrix M1 which has exactly rank(M) many columns (this is what the first while loop does). After that, I keep removing the columns one by one to check if the rest of the columns contain T in their span (this is the second while loop). In the second while loop, I first remove a column from M2 (which is essentially a copy of M1) and call this matrix M3. To M3. I augment the vector T and check if the rank decreases. Since T was already in the span of M2, rank([M2 T]) should be the same as rank(M2). Now by removing column c and augmenting T to M2 doesn't decrease the rank, then I know that c is not necessary to generate T. This way I only keep those columns that are necessary to generate T.

It does return correct answers for the examples I tried, but I am going to run this code on a matrix with entries which vary a lot in magnitude (say the  maximum is as large as 20^20 and minimum is 1)and typically the matrix dimensions could go up to 300. So planning to run it over a set of few hundred test cases over the weekend. It'll be really helpful if you can tell me if something looks fishy/wrong -- for eg. will I run into precision errors? How should I modify my code so that it works for all values/ranges as mentioned above? Also, if there is any way to speed up my code (or write the same thing in a shorter/nicer way), I'd like to know.

```
R = 155
C= 167
T = vector(QQ, R)
M1 = matrix(ZZ, R, C)

M1 = M
C1 = C
i2 = 0

if rank(M.augment(T)) == rank(M):
 print("The rank of M is")
 print(rank(M))
 while i2 < C1 :
  if rank(M1.delete_columns([i2])) == rank(M1) :
   M1 = M1.delete_columns([i2])   
   C1 = C1 - 1
  else :
   i2 = i2+1

 C2 = M1.ncols()
 print("The number of columns in the trimmed down matrix M1 is")
 print(C2)


 i3 = 0
 M2 = M1
 print("The rank of M1 which is now also the rank of M2 is")
 print(rank(M2))
 while i3 < C2 :
  M3 = M2.delete_columns([i3])
  if rank(M3.augment(T)) < rank(M2) :
   M2 = M3
   C2 = C2 - 1
  else :
   i3 = i3 + 1

print("Rank of matrix M is")
print(M.rank())
```

Comment: I'm also curious how the rank packages work in Sage. It gives me different (and mostly wrong for my purposes) answers, when I declare the matrix M to be over reals -- that is I use MatrixSpace(RR, R,C) instead of MatrixSpace(QQ,R,C) -- why does this happen? For my purpose I need the exact rank of the matrix and not a numerical approximation based on number of singular values greater than some tolerace (which is what I think matlab does, which led me to use Sage). I tried to use symbolic rank -- MatrixSpace(SR, R, C)  but it made the code super slow. So any pointers/tips around these lines?

Comment: I am not a numerical analyst, but I believe that rank computations for matrices tend to be very sensitive to small changes in the entries of the matrix, so rank computations over inexact fields like RR are suspect. Over a field like QQ, which is exact (no numerical uncertainty), rank works well.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to use Sage to decide whether a vector `T` was in the image of some a matrix `M1` constructed from some subset of columns of another matrix `M`, I would do this:

```
M1 = M.matrix_from_columns([list of indices of the columns to use])
T in M1.column_space()
```

or use a while loop to modify `M1` each time, as you do. (But I think `T in M1.column_space()` should work better than testing equality of ranks.)